# Highcharts Spline not drawing graph lines for first 30 points.

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a highcharts spline graph that works pretty well. I changed around some of the ajax calls and now it won't draw the lines connecting the first 30 or so points.  It just draws the points for awhile and then the lines come in.  I'm more concerned with the lines than the points.

Does anyone know why it does this?  Please see my code below.  Thanks in advance for any help!

```
var results_a;
var results_b;
var flag_a = 1;
var flag_b = 1;
var current_a;
var current_b;
var previous_a = 0;
var previous_b = 0;
var xmlhttp_a;
var xmlhttp_b;
var url_a = "http://mysite.com/web/johnsNumber.txt"; 
var url_b = "http://mysite.com/web/johnsNumber.txt";
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////         
function loadFirstDoc(url_a,cfunc)
{
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp_a=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
  else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp_a=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp_a.onreadystatechange=cfunc;
  xmlhttp_a.open("GET",url_a,true);
  xmlhttp_a.send();
}

function myFunction_a()
{
  loadFirstDoc(url_a,function()
    {
       if (xmlhttp_a.readyState==4 && xmlhttp_a.status==200)
        {
            current_a = parseInt(xmlhttp_a.responseText);
            flag_a = 1;
        }
    });
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////   
function loadSecondDoc(url_b,cfunc)
{
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp_b=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp_b=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
    xmlhttp_b.onreadystatechange=cfunc;
    xmlhttp_b.open("GET",url_b,true);
    xmlhttp_b.send();
}

function myFunction_b()
{
loadSecondDoc(url_b,function()
  {
     if (xmlhttp_b.readyState==4 && xmlhttp_b.status==200)
     {
        current_b = parseInt(xmlhttp_b.responseText);
        flag_b = 1;
     }
  });
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function randInRange(start, end){
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * (end-start+1) + start);
}

function is_numeric(input){
    return !isNaN(input);
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/*js for first graph....container*/
$(function () {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Apply the grey theme
        Highcharts.setOptions({
           colors: ["#B00000"],

        });

        Highcharts.setOptions({
            global: {
                useUTC: false
            }
        });

        var chart;
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'spline',
                animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
                marginRight: 10,
                events: {
                    load: function() {

                        // set up the updating of the chart each second
                        var series = this.series[0];
                        setInterval(function() {

                            myFunction_a(); //ajax call

                            //check  if flag has been set...if so, then random number
                            if(flag_a == 1){
                                results_a = current_b;
                             ; //results_a = randInRange(1, 5);
                            }
                            //flag not set so results = 0
                            else{
                              results_a = 0;
                            }
                            //Need to write to a text file right here
                            var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                                y = results_a;
                                series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                            //series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                            previous_a = current_a;
                            flag_a = 0;
                        }, 1500);
                    }
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Linux Server Sales Graph',
                style: {
                  color: '#B00000',
                  font: 'bold 20px Lucida Grande, Lucida Sans Unicode, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif'
                }            
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                tickPixelInterval: 150
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: -1,
                max: 6,
                title: {
                    text: 'Sales'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#000',
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                        Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) +'<br/>'+
                        Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'sales/sec',
                data: (function() {
                    // generate an array of random data
                    var data = [],
                        time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                        i;

                    for (i = -19; i <= 0; i++) {
                        data.push({
                            x: time + i * 1000,
                            y: randInRange(1, 5)
                        });
                    }
                    return data;
                })()
            }]
        });
    });

});
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/*script for the second graph...container2*/
$(function () {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        Highcharts.setOptions({
           colors: ["#0000FF"],
        });
        Highcharts.setOptions({
            global: {
                useUTC: false
            }
        });

        var chart;
        $('#container2').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'spline',
                animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
                marginRight: 10,
                events: {
                    load: function() {

                        // set up the updating of the chart each second
                        var series = this.series[0];
                        setInterval(function() {
                            myFunction_b();
                            if(flag_b == 1){
                                results_b = current_b;
                              //results_b = randInRange(1, 5);
                            }
                            else{
                              results_b = 0;
                            }
                           //need to write to text file right here
                            var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                                y = results_b;
                            //series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                            series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                            previous_b = current_b;
                            flag_b = 0;
                        }, 1500);
                    }
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Windows Server Sales Graph',
                style: {
                  color: '#0000FF',
                  font: 'bold 20px Lucida Grande, Lucida Sans Unicode, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif'
                }   
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                tickPixelInterval: 150
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: -1,
                max: 6,
                title: {
                    text: 'Sales'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#000',
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                        Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) +'<br/>'+
                        Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'sales/sec',
                data: (function() {
                    // generate an array of random data
                    var data = [],
                        time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                        i;

                    for (i = -19; i <= 0; i++) {
                        data.push({
                            x: time + i * 1000,
                            y: randInRange(1, 5)
                        });
                    }
                    return data;
                })()
            }]
        });
    });

});
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: a fiddle would be so much easier to help

Comment: I can't really fiddle when the problem is tied to my calls to my server

Answer (score 0):

1) In first chart:

```
 if(flag_a == 1){
     results_a = current_b;
     //results_a = randInRange(1, 5);
 }
```

shouldn't be there `current_a` ?

2) I have created simple chart: http://jsfiddle.net/3bQne/102/ with your options. Only difference is that value is always the same. As you can see, it works perfectly fine.

3) Do you have any errors in console? Try to udpate my example to reproduce issue.